# Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I'm trying to determine the best way to truncate or drop extra decimal places in SQL without rounding.  For example:

```
declare @value decimal(18,2)

set @value = 123.456
```

This will automatically round `@value` to be `123.46`, which is good in most cases.  However, for this project, I don't need that.  Is there a simple way to truncate the decimals I don't need?  I know I can use the `left()` function and convert back to a decimal.  Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You will need to provide 3 numbers to the ROUND function.

1. number  **Required. The number to be rounded**
2. decimals **Required. The number of decimal places to round number to
   operation**
3. *Optional. If 0, it rounds the result to the number of decimal. If another value than 0, it truncates the result to the number of decimals. Default value is 0*

Example:

```
   select round(123.456, 2, 1)
```

Works in:

- SQL Server (starting with 2008), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse

*Additional Info: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp*

Comment: The answer should explain what the parameters of the function are

Comment: SQL ROUND(number, decimals, operation) : operation --> If 0, it rounds the result to the number of decimal. If another value than 0, it truncates the result to the number of decimals. Default is 0

Comment: you are a life saver, i had a amount to show last two digits only "1.9991666", however it always rounded up to 2 no matter what I use, with this I am able to achieve something like this -  select FORMAT(round(1.9991666, 2, 1),'N2') AS 'Rate', Thanks mate

Comment: For this eg: it does not return the value : 123.45, rather it returns the value 123.450.
Please advice and help.
I am using SQL 14

Answer (score 323):

```
ROUND ( 123.456 , 2 , 1 )
```

[When the third parameter **!= 0** it truncates rather than rounds.](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql#arguments)

**Syntax**

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

**Arguments**

- `numeric_expression`
  Is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data
  type category, except for the bit data type.
- `length`
  Is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded. length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the decimal point, as specified by length.
- `function`
  Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

Comment: Anybody know what values for the function argument correspond to tinyint, smallint and int? Microsoft left that part out of their documentation and can't find the answer anywhere. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: MS SQL SERVER rounds numbers a bit differently than IQ.  
To fix use the round(x,y,z) function like this
round(val1/val2,4,1)

Answer (score 51):

```
SELECT Cast(Round(123.456,2,1) as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's the way I was able to truncate and not round:

```
select 100.0019-(100.0019%.001)
```

returns 100.0010

And your example:

```
select 123.456-(123.456%.001)
```

returns 123.450

Now if you want to get rid of the ending zero, simply cast it:

```
select cast((123.456-(123.456%.001)) as decimal (18,2))
```

returns 123.45

Answer (score 13):

Actually whatever the third parameter is, 0 or 1 or 2, it will not round your value.

```
CAST(ROUND(10.0055,2,0) AS NUMERIC(10,2))
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The given SQL results in 10.01, which is a correct rounding of 10.0055 to two decimal places. If the final parameter is not 0, the value is truncated (to 2 decimal places) to 10.00.

Answer (score 9):

Do you want the decimal or not?

If not, use

```
select ceiling(@value),floor(@value)
```

If you do it with 0 then do a round:

```
select round(@value,2)
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I need to keep the decimal places, just drop the ones that I don't want. For example, instead of 123.456 in my example above being converted to 123.46...I want to drop the third decimal and make it 123.45.

Answer (score 7):

```
ROUND(number, decimals, operation)
```

number => Required. The number to be rounded
decimals => Required. The number of decimal places to round number to
operation => Optional. If 0, it rounds the result to the number of decimal. If another value than 0, it truncates the result to the number of decimals. Default value is 0

```sql
SELECT ROUND(235.415, 2, 1)
```

will give you `235.410`

```sql
SELECT ROUND(235.415, 0, 1)
```

will give you `235.000`

But now trimming`0` you can use `cast`

```sql
SELECT CAST(ROUND(235.415, 0, 1) AS INT)
```

will give you `235`

Answer (score 6):

Another truncate with no rounding solution and example.

```
    Convert 71.950005666 to a single decimal place number (71.9)
    1) 71.950005666 * 10.0 = 719.50005666
    2) Floor(719.50005666) = 719.0
    3) 719.0 / 10.0 = 71.9

    select Floor(71.950005666 * 10.0) / 10.0
```

Comment: +1 for `Floor()` which is the way to go to drop decimals without rounding indeed. Too bad Floor() has no second parameter to indicate at which position. But I think the * 10) / 10 works around this quite well indeed.

Answer (score 6):

Round has an optional parameter

```
Select round(123.456, 2, 1)  will = 123.45
Select round(123.456, 2, 0)  will = 123.46
```

Comment: Select round(123.456, 2, 1)  will = 123.450

Comment: I don't see why this gets upvotes. The above will give you 123.450 and 123.460 respectively.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove the decimal part of any number

```
SELECT ROUND(@val,0,1)
```

Comment: It does not. SELECT ROUND(123.4560,0,1) gives you 123.0000 instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CAST(Value as Decimal(10,2)) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Would give you 2 values after the decimal point. (MS SQL SERVER)

Comment: I do not believe this is correct
Consider the following case and notice that the result is rounded up instead of Truncated. OP wants it truncated.
` DECLARE @N1 AS DECIMAL(10,7) = 123.1234789
` PRINT @N1
` SELECT CAST(@N1 AS DECIMAL(10,4))

Answer (score 2):

Another way is **`ODBC TRUNCATE`** function:

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(18,3) =123.456;

SELECT @value AS val, {fn TRUNCATE(@value, 2)} AS result
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/XABA61021)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║   val   ║ result  ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ 123,456 ║ 123,450 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

Remark:

I recommend using built-in `ROUND` function with 3rd parameter set to 1.

Comment: ODBC Scalar Function - Different Alternative !

Answer (score 2):

If you desire to take some number like `89.0904987` and turn it into `89.09` by simply omitting the undesired decimal places, simply use the following:

```
select cast(yourColumnName as decimal(18,2))
```

The following screenshot is from [W3Schools SQL Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) section, which describes what `decimal(18,2)` is doing:

[image: Screenshot from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp]

Therefore,

```
select cast(89.0904987 as decimal(18,2))
```

gives you: `89.09`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late but I don't see it as an answer and have been using this trick for years.

Simply subtract .005 from your value and use Round(@num,2).

Your example:

```
declare @num decimal(9,5) = 123.456

select round(@num-.005,2)
```

returns 123.45

It will automatically adjust the rounding to the correct value you are looking for.

By the way, are you recreating the program from the movie Office Space?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT cast(round(123.456,2,1) as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code for converting 3 decimal values  after a point into 2 decimal places:

```
declare @val decimal (8, 2)
select @val = 123.456
select @val =  @val

select @val
```

The output is 123.46

Comment: 1) 3rd line is completely unnecessary
2) he explicitly said he didn't want to round the number, but truncate it (the result should be 123.45)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want only the decimal value,
in this case you can use the following:

```
declare @val decimal (8, 3)
SET @val = 123.456

SELECT @val - ROUND(@val,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but nobody used sub-strings to round.  This as advantage the ability to round really long numbers (limit of your string in SQL server which is usually 8000 characters):

```
SUBSTRING('123.456', 1, CHARINDEX('.', '123.456') + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can go much easier with simpler example solution found in Hackerrank:

> Problem statement: Query the greatest value of the Northern Latitudes
>   (LAT_N) from STATION that is less than 137.2345. Truncate your answer
>   to 4 decimal places.

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(MAX(LAT_N),4)
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N < 137.23453;
```

Solution Above gives you idea how to simply make value limited to 4 decimal points. If you want to lower or upper the numbers after decimal, just change 4 to whatever you want.

Answer (score -3):

`Mod(x,1)` is the easiest way I think.

Answer (score -6):

```
select convert(int,@value)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wanted. He still wants decimal places, but he wants to remove them (truncte) rather than rounding them. I.E. 123.456  -> 123.45 NOT 123.456 -> 12.46 and NOT 123.456 -> 123