# SQL Server 2008: Why won't this round to two decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, rounding

```
SELECT
   ROUND(WeightInOZ / 16, 2)as WeightInLbs
FROM
   Inventory
```

The result I get looks like an integer 1,2 etc

Comment: What is the data type of `WeightInOZ`?

Comment: it is an int, but i didn't think it would matter because i ammanipulating the result

Comment: Possible duplicate (out of votes?!?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server

Comment: @OMG: I don't think that's a duplicate (though I'd be surprised if there isn't a duplicate on SO, considering this is a pretty common mistake...I didn't bother looking, though)

Comment: @Adam Robinson: The OP comments suggest rounding with truncation, which is what the link provides.

Comment: @OMG: The link is asking how to truncate the number; this OP is basically asking the opposite ("Why is it truncating when I want it to round?")

Comment: @Adam Robinson: No, you need to read the discussion in Abe's answer -- you've got it backwards.

Comment: @OMG: No, that was a discussion subsequent to actually doing the rounding; the OP's column is an integer, which (with the syntax above using `16`) resulted in integer division (in other words, trucation). Abe and I both posted answers that addressed that problem; his later issue was not about rounding but in presentation (in other words, the value was properly rounded but had trailing zeros).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing 16 to 16.0

```
SELECT
   ROUND(WeightInOZ / 16.0, 2)as WeightInLbs
FROM
   Inventory
```

You are seeing strange results because it is treating the results of your division as an integer rather than a decimal.  Specifying the `.0` tells sql server to treat it as a decimal.

**UPDATE:**

If the trailing zero's are freaking you out you can always do this:

```
SELECT
   CAST(ROUND(WeightInOZ / 16.0, 2) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) as WeightInLbs
FROM
   Inventory
```

Comment: that will give me this result: 0.060000 which is definitley on rigth track

Comment: Hmm, what result are you expecting?

Comment: i am expecting 0.06 or 233.23 etc

Comment: I know it looks weird but those are the same numbers.  If you don't like seeing the trailing zeros you can use the method described in my update.

Comment: `money` seems to work just as well as `numeric(8,2)` in this case.

Comment: adding the '.0' makes it a floating point literal, not a decimal literal.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this:

```
WeightInOZ / 16
```

Since you're dealing with two integers, SQL Server truncates the remainder, so by there's no fractional component for it to round.

What you want to do is force it to perform floating-point (or decimal) division. The easiest way would be to change `16` to `16.0`.

```
SELECT
   ROUND(WeightInOZ / 16.0, 2)as WeightInLbs
FROM
   Inventory
```

Comment: @Nicholas: Is the first part of your comment missing?