# SQL Search a Numeric Field for non whole numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a DB that has a numeric field and I need to search  all the rows and return only the non whole numbers.

I have tried the query below and it keeps retuning records that have 0.

```
SELECT
 li.QTY
FROM
  TABLE LI
WHERE
  li.QTY  like '%.%'
```

Comment: Sorry, i cast to varchar i left out of the exapmle

Comment: Here is a related question... Just apply these practices with the `<>` to your column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use LIKE only with char fields, not with number (integer or float) ones.

If by "whole numbers" you mean 0.0 , 2.0 , -5.0 , etc. and not 12.5 , 0.67 then this can do:

```
SELECT li.QTY 
  FROM TABLE LI 
  WHERE li.QTY != ROUND(li.QTY , 0)
;
```

(for SQL-Server: edited the TRUNC into ROUND)
You could also use the FLOOR or CEILING functions:

```
SELECT li.QTY 
  FROM TABLE LI 
  WHERE li.QTY != FLOOR(li.QTY)
;
```

Comment: This correct except he want's **non-whole** numbers. Just switch your `=` to `<>`. He could do the exact same logic using `ROUND` and `CAST AS INT`... just figure out which is fastest!

Comment: Looking for any number with a decimal

Comment: Yes, thnx. ROUND and CEILING functions would work the same here. Not sure if CAST as INT would be faster, probably not.

Comment: @ypercube so would `FLOOR` ... I bet one of these depends on some other one though. He should just test to see which is fastest for his dataset.

Comment: ypercube - you __can__ use LIKE with numeric data. As long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: About the CAST AS INT, i just thought that it may not work in some cases. It would depend on the accuracy of the INT and the number converted.

Answer (score 3):

Why it does **not** work.  When QTY is a numeric column, when you display it, or implicitly convert to varchar (LIKE does it implicitly), ALL numbers will be cast to the same number of decimal places.

Consider this SQL statement

```
with TBL(qty) as (select 1.1 union all select 3)
SELECT li.QTY FROM TBL LI WHERE li.QTY like '%.%'
```

Output

```
1.1
3.0   << this contains "." even if it does not need to
```

Cast it to a bigint and it will drop any decimals, then compare it again.

```
SELECT li.QTY FROM TBL LI
WHERE li.QTY <> CAST(qty as bigint)
```

---

If you MUST use LIKE (or just for show..)

```
SELECT li.QTY, CONVERT(varchar, li.qty)
FROM TBL LI
WHERE li.QTY LIKE '%.%[^0]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--Most Def...Cast as an int...Save you from validation of anything. Especially for conversions of dates into a whole date since Microsoft does not like a round down date function.

--For example:

--For every 300 hours an employee works they receive 1 whole day of vacation

--partial days of vacation will not be counted

Declare 

@SumHours as decimal(38,10),

@VacationValidation as int

Set @SumHours = 3121.30000000000000000000
Set @VacationValidation = 300

Select cast(((@SumHours)/(@VacationValidation)) as int)
Select day(((@SumHours)/(@VacationValidation))) -1

--without casting as an int, I would need to validated the Day function to make sure that I'm not 

--offsetting a whole day by one day.
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST function work for me.

```
SELECT li.QTY FROM TABLE LI WHERE li.QTY != CAST(li.QTY AS  INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @Value AS float

SET @Value = 250.00

CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',(CAST(b.Value/@Value as char))) = 0 THEN 'WholeNumber' ELSE 'Fraction' END AS mResult

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to guess from seeing the code. Also, when answering old questions you need to indicate how the answer improves existing answers. That said, frankly I wonder *how* this answers the question. Also, it isn't correct syntax.