# Truncate (not round) decimal in SQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, truncate, rounding

I'm doing astored procedure using a MySQL database.
How could I round or truncate a FLOAT variable with diferent decimals?

I've found this answer: [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Are any solution using just PL, not PL/SQL?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Finally done, I'm using another variable DECIMAL(10,n) where n is the number of decimals. For example: SET var DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 5,50;