# How to use TRUNC function in SQL server 2012, as am getting 'TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.'?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How to use `TRUNC` function in SQL Server 2012, as I am getting an error:

> 'TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

when I execute the statement

```
SELECT TRUNC(30.95, 1)
```

in SQL Server 2012

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634907.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: But, my question is, Can I use 'TRUNC' as such in SQL Server? Why Am I getting it as not recognized built in function? As per the below link i should be able to execute SELECT TRUNC(30.95,1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634907.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a DAX function, not a built in SQL function. It looks like those would be for use in Excel.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399181.aspx

The built in function for SQL Server 2012 are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
ROUND ( 30.95 , 1 , 1 )
```

When the third parameter **!= 0** it truncates rather than rounds

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44093/44743

Comment: But, my question is, Can I use 'TRUNC' as such in SQL Server? Why Am I getting it as not recognized built in function? As per the below link i should be able to execute SELECT TRUNC(30.95,1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634907.aspx

Comment: The 3rd parameter is a sql 2016 only feature.  this issue is for sql 2012 so the round function wont truncate it.

Comment: @Kevbo:  That's what the documentation says, but I have a working SQL 2014 instance right in front of me that understands it too.  I think older versions actually support it too.  In fact, this answer dates from 2013, so it seems likely that support goes back at least as far as 2012.