# control in display Decimal separators in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem in display the decimal numbers, it has many number.

My sql statement :

```
Select sum(HS$totalMoney)
```

the result :

```
12132.123444343
```

I want to display as  `12132.12` without the another number

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your logic is for money you should first round the values not truncate

`select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),round(12132.123444343 ,2))` gives `12132.12`

`select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),round(12132.125944343 ,2))` gives `12132.13`

Comment: i want not convert 12.126 to   12.13  but just cut

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(21, 2), sum(HS$totalMoney))
-- This one will round in SQL Server but truncate in ASE 15 (which was available to me at the time)

SELECT CONVERT(decimal(21, 2), round(sum(HS$totalMoney), 2, 1))
-- This one uses a variant of ROUND supported by SQL Server, but not ASE 15 (and will truncate the third and subsequent decimal places).
```

Comment: i want not convert 12.126 to   12.13  but just cut

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT CAST(12132.123444343 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: i want not convert 12.126 to   12.13  but just cut

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mysql, use code blew

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(sum(HS$totalMoney), 2);
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRUNCATE'. not work

Answer (score 1):

this query slove your problem

```
SELECT CAST(12132.123444343 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

or you can use

```
select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),round(12132.1255555 ,2))
```

Comment: i want not convert 12.126 to   12.13  but just cut

Answer (score 1):

The round function has a function parameter to truncate instead of round:

`select round(12132.123444343 , 2, 1)`

From here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Comment: here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server) is a SO question covering it as well.