# Truncate decimals from column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, truncate, rounding, decimal

How would I delete all the decimals from a column in SQL Server 2008?

If I have a column `X_Coord` and had three rows with the value, how would I trim it so that there are NO decimals after the last whole number?

For example, let's say my table is called `RCMP`, and the column is below:

```
X_Coord
---------------
- 5588790.77000
- 5588873.79000
- 5588943.71000
```

How would I remove the decimals in a single query?

I tried `ROUND`, but that ends up making the values appear as ie `5588790.00000`.

I want it to appear as: `5588790`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: its different. that solution did not work at all.

Comment: i think the FLOOR function will help i just don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the decimal data type to an integer.

```
SELECT CAST(x_coord AS INT)
FROM dbo.RMCP
```

**Edit:**  I have updated the code to reflect how to change the data type.  This is a big impact change so be very careful.  I would urge you to test this in development.

```
if object_id('#Demo') is not null
drop table #Demo;
go

create table #Demo(x_coord decimal(12,5))
insert into #Demo values(5588790.77000),(5588873.79000),(5588943.71000)

alter table #Demo
ALTER COLUMN x_coord INT NULL

select *
from #Demo
GO
```

--or this works

```
if object_id('#Demo') is not null
drop table #Demo;
go

create table #Demo(x_coord decimal(12,5))
insert into #Demo values(5588790.77000),(5588873.79000),(5588943.71000)

alter table #Demo
add new_x_coord INT NULL

UPDATE #Demo SET new_x_coord = CAST(x_coord AS INT)
GO

--**********************  dont drop anything until you confirm the data is good!!!!!!!!!!!!! and test this in development *************************************
ALTER TABLE #Demo
DROP COLUMN x_coord

exec sp_rename 'dbo.#Demo.new_x_coord','x_coord','COLUMN'

select *
from #Demo
GO
```

Comment: thanks, but this just selects it. I need to convert the column.

Comment: You will need to change the data type of the column to int or add a new column and execute an update statement with the cast above to load the new column.  Then you can drop the old column.