# GET n decimal places without round in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimalformat

I need to select just two digits from decimal values in SQL Server

```
16.987490   --> 16.98
8.0189918   -->  8.01
34.5566901  --> 34.55
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

You can Use `ROUND`

```
select CAST(ROUND (16.987490  , 2 , 1 ) as NUMERIC(18,2))
select CAST(ROUND (8.0189918  , 2 , 1 ) as NUMERIC(18,2))
select CAST(ROUND (34.5566901  , 2 , 1 ) as NUMERIC(18,2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
16.98
8.01
34.55
```

Comment: @MartinSmith now updated

Comment: it works fine, thaks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to subtract 0.005 and use `round()`, `str()`, or `cast()`:

```
select round(val - 0.005, 2)
```

Comment: it does not work in all case.

Comment: @CHIRINGUCHI - You're not going to provide an example case with that comment?

Comment: select round(16.106734639876674323534635490 - 0.005, 2)

Comment: @CHIRINGUCHI - Returns a result with datatype `numeric(30, 27)` with value `16.1`. What's the issue with that? The trailing spaces when viewed in SSMS?

Comment: @CHIRINGUCHI `select CAST(round(16.106734639876674323534635490 - 0.005, 2)  as numeric(18, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dec decimal(15,5)

set @dec = 16.987490

select cast(@dec as decimal(19,2))
```

So the solution is to "force" a conversion to a scale of 2.

solution 2 since first doesn't work:

```
declare @dec decimal(15,5)

set @dec = 8.0189918

select cast(substring(cast(@dec as varchar(50)), 0, CHARINDEX('.', cast(@dec as varchar(50)), 1) + 3) as decimal(19,2))
```

Comment: Doesn't produce the desired result for input 8.0189918 (returns `8.02` not `8.01`)

Comment: yes, it rounds it to .02 since there is an 8 after 1 and 8 > 5. New idea soon..

Comment: The Second solution works fine

Comment: Thanks! Though, I think Ganesh's answer is more elegant :)