# How to remove decimal places in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting a value in SQL server column like following:-

**1667.7500000000000**

Now i need to convert above value just like below value:-

**1667**

I want to remove .75 and also all zero's(i don't want to round it to 1668). Please anyone guide and share sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this query being used? Why would you want to format the number in sql? Why wouldn't you format it in code or in a report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

can you use a round transaction?

if so here ya go

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all
I have solved myself using

CAST(MYVALUE AS INT)