# prevent rounding off a number

Tags: sql-server

In want to prevent a float value from rounding up-
If I have my value Case =34.9562 , I wish to see number only upto 1 decimal place which is 34.9 and if it is null then show as blank('').

I'm trying different ways to prevent it from rounding by applying cast to decimal(4,1) and things like that but nothing seems to be able to prevent it.

The database used is Sql server 2005.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: If you want precise numbers why are you using the float datatype in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cast` and `round` should work:

```
SELECT  cast(round(34.9562,1,1) as float)
```

To show null as blank(''), you can use `case` statement and do something like this

```
select case when field_name is null then ''
       else cast(round(field_name,1,1) as float) 
       end as my_new_value
from your_table
```