# Casting columns in SQL Server for SSIS package purpose

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, type-conversion, etl

I stuck with casting data in SQL Server. I'm doing a SSIS package to transfer data from SQL Server to an Oracle database, and in Oracle, I have columns with these types:

```
Registered_hours: number(3,1)
Approved_hours: number(4,2)
```

which represents full hours with halfs. I mean for ex: 3.5h

And in my SQL Server database, I have these columns, but I store minutes instead of hours. So I have values for ex: 480 (8 hours).

```
Registered_hours: int
Approved_hours: int
```

How to correctly cast/convert this values? For example: in SQL Server, I have 510 minutes which is equivalent to 8.5 hour. And I need to get this value after converting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to convert (for example) 510 to 8.5. If that's so, would this do any good?

You need only the last, *converted* value, but I chose to do it step-by-step so that you'd see why and how I did that.

```
SQL> with test as (select 65 minutes from dual union
  2                select 480        from dual union
  3                select 510        from dual)
  4  select minutes,
  5    trunc(minutes / 60) hours,
  6    round((minutes - (trunc(minutes / 60) * 60)) / 60, 2) hours_add,
  7    --
  8    trunc(minutes / 60) +
  9    round((minutes - (trunc(minutes / 60) * 60)) / 60, 2) converted
 10  from test;

   MINUTES      HOURS  HOURS_ADD  CONVERTED
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        65          1        ,08       1,08
       480          8          0          8
       510          8         ,5        8,5

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this is it what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @tylkonachwile you have to accept this answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: @Littlefoot Would you be so kind and tell how to achive the same in MSSQL? I Mean how to get 8,5 from 510, because trunc isn't recognized function in MSSQL :)

Comment: @tylkonachwile if you are using SSIS why not using `Derived Column trasnformation`? It is designed for similar cases!

Comment: sure you have right, i am just so fresh with ssis, thanks one more time :)

Comment: As of MSSQL, have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

You can add a derived columns using `Derived Column Transformation` with the following expressions *(Hours = minutes / 60)*

*I used `(DT_NUMERIC,10,0)` because `Registered_hours / 60` return an integer value without it*

```
(DT_NUMERIC,3,1)((DT_NUMERIC,10,0)Registered_hours / 60)
```

and

```
(DT_NUMERIC,4,2)((DT_NUMERIC,10,0)Approved_hours/ 60)
```

**References**

- [Derived Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation)