# How to display maximum 2 decimal points if we have less than 2 decimal point it should display real value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Example:

- 10 should display 10
- 10.3 should display 10.3
- 10.50 should display 10.50
- 10.246 should display 10.24
- 10.2568 should display 10.25
- 10.38754 should display 10.38 etc

If there are more than 2 digits after the decimal points, it should truncate.

I have to implement this in a stored procedure. Frontend application is only exe, unable to change.

Comment: This should be done at the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: Display where? Why not set the display format on the UI/presentation layer/report?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),column_name)`?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Answer is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: Databases don't display anything.  Front End Applications, Client Applications, etc, etc, they display string representations of numeric data for a user to read.  If you want to round/truncate a value, to actually change the VALUE of something, doing that in a database makes sense.  If you want to FORMAT the string REPRESENTATION of a numeric datatype, do that in whatever client you're using to display the data.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this belongs in the Presentation Layer, but if you must...

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Value decimal(16,6))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(10.00)
,(10.3)
,(10.53)
,(10.246)

Select *
      ,NewString = format(round(Value,2,1),'0.##')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Value       NewString
10.000000   10
10.300000   10.3
10.530000   10.53
10.246000   10.24   -- Note not rounded to 10.25
```

Comment: Value            NewString
10.000000   10.00,
10.300000   10.30,
10.530000   10.53,
10.246000   10.24,

Comment: @vinodkumar Are you not using the Format() portion ?

Comment: @vinodkumar  The ## in the format indicate optional display

Comment: @vinodkumar  Just to be clear.  The format returns a string value AND though format() has some nice features, it is not know as a performer.  Should be used sparingly

Comment: why 10.30 it is displaying 10.3 i am expecting 10.30

Comment: @vinodkumar not according to your question

Comment: it is there in my example 10.50 should display 10.50

Comment: @vinodkumar why 10.3 and not 10.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `FORMAT` function

```
declare @value float
set @value = 10.245


select format(@value,'0.0#') as formatted_value
```

will show `10.26`

if you want to truncate is even faster:

```
select round(@value,2,1)
```

will show `10.25`

Comment: this shows `10.26` for `10.2568` that is not what he wanted

Comment: try it then, it will show `10.26` and he wants `10.25`

Comment: Your example will display 10.25, not 10.24. This is because format will round it which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: You update this as I was posting my comment. I would remove the format option and just leave the round solution....that is what will work.

Comment: I'll leave both solutions, maybe the first one will become useful to a future visitor

Comment: OK but your format solution doesn't work for this question.