# SQL - Cut off at 6th decimal place

Tags: sql

So, I have a value 123.123456789, and I'm trying to return 123.123456. The query I tried below rounds the 6th decimal digit to the next number. Please help to return 123.123456 ONLY. (No rounding!)

```
select cast(cast(123.123456789 as DECIMAL(9,6)) as float)
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: This is my obligatory comment that these operations should be done in the _display_ layer (app, form, report, etc.). The data layer should only be concerned with managing data, not waht is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The first param is your number, second is the precision, and the third is a number that indicates if the rounding should truncate (0 rounds, any other number truncates).

```
select cast(cast(round(123.123456789,6,1) as DECIMAL(9,6)) as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select round(numeric_expression, length [, function])`

**Arguments**

*numeric_expression*
Is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data type category, except for the bit data type.

*length*
Is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded. length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the decimal point, as specified by length.

*function*
Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017