# Dividing by decimal values - rounding issue

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to divide two decimal values, in hope they will return the following; 1.132930.

However, SQL appears to be rounding the value to 1.132931.

The value returned before conversion is 1.1329305135951.

The SQL code i'm using is as follows:

```
DECLARE @p1 DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @p2 DECIMAL(10,2)

SET @p1 = 225.00
SET @p2 = 198.60

SELECT Cast(@p1/@p2 AS DECIMAL(9,6))
```

Comment: So you want it to round down, not round?

Comment: But it makes sense to round "051" to "1" rather than "0".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the value before the cast as following:

```
DECLARE @p1 DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @p2 DECIMAL(10,2)

SET @p1 = 225.00
SET @p2 = 198.60

SELECT Cast(ROUND(@p1/@p2,6,1) AS DECIMAL(9,6))
```