# 1/n to 8 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a formula:

```
1 / cast(replace(count(usertbl.[name]) over (partition by usertbl.[name], calendar.[Date]), 0, 1) as decimal(2,0)) as [WorkDays]
```

Let's assume the count partition brings back 6, so the formula is effectively 1/6. Currently, it brings back 0.17 (so 0.17* 6 = 1.02).

I want to approximate as close as possible to 1 when I multiply the partitioned decimal by count. So 0.16666667*6 = 1.00000002 which is better than 1.02.

How can I change the above formula to achieve 8 decimal places? I tried decimal (10,8) without success.

I'm not trying to reduce the decimal places but to increase it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Comment: My goal is actually the reverse of this thread's goal I think. Instead of 1/6 or 0.17 I want to get 0.1666667 so more decimals than less.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you simply use this?

```
1.0 / cast(count(*) over (partition by usertbl.[name], calendar.[Date]) as [WorkDays]
```

I have no idea what the `replace()` is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

try casting the 1 to float or desired decimal precision, if your count is 6 your query would seems like

```
select cast(1.0 as float) / cast(replace(6, 0, 1) as decimal(2,0))
```

see fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d72bf3f3f34dc4a395535da02c0722b9

Comment: This does fix the issue, but not on my query. I think I have another issue. But yes if i were to cast numerator as float and denominator as decimal --let's say (8,6)--I'd get the desired number format.

Comment: @72444ajax just for curiosity, why the replace 0 to 1 in the count?